# Navigation Drawer update listView and avoid crash

Tags: android

Anyone can tell me why the Drawer Layout crashes when pressing the menu button ?

my main question is about updateing the listView? Could i just add strings and putt them under the listView or should the menu be changed to a framelayout and add buttons on it ?

hope my english isn't to bad!

### EDIT

i now have problem with PlanetFragments

```
/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
```

PlanetFragment cannot be resolved

andthe first problem with crashing is from here

```
/** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
```

Comment: Add your code, and your LogCat error to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSupportActionBar()`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
```